# How to use Subclassing API to build a Dynamic model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dynamic, neural-network, google-colaboratory

```
class WideAndDeepModel(keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, units=30, activation='relu', **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
    self.hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
    self.main_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)
    self.aux_output = keras.layers.Dense(1)

  def call(self, inputs):
    input_A, input_B = inputs
    hidden1 = self.hidden1(input_B)
    hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
    concat = keras.layers.Concatenate([input_A, hidden2])
    main_output = self.main_output(concat)
    aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
    return main_output, aux_output

model = WideAndDeepModel()

model.compile(loss=['mse', 'mse'], loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer="sgd")

history = model.fit(
    [X_train_A, X_train_B], [y_train, y_train], epochs=20,
    validation_data=([X_valid_A, X_valid_B], [y_valid, y_valid])
)
```

I want to run with 20 epochs but it showd me the value error:

> ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). This could be due to issues in input pipeline that resulted in an empty dataset. Otherwise, please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Google colab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10CW2T3NIFSakCTffrX90GiLdAjZyi1Tb?usp=sharing
I want to train with the Dynamic model and predict new data.